# Order of references in output file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am running MikTex with Texmaker on a Windows 10 PC. My MikTeX bibliography sort of works, but the order of references in the final output file just mirrors the order in the .bib file and so the first reference quoted in the final document, which should be labelled [1], could be listed as [27] for example, which is just its sequence in the bib file. I must be doing something wrong. Any suggestions please? I have a mixture of @article and @book references.

Comment: the order in the bib file almost never has any effect, most bib styles specify order of appearance (unsorted) or alphabetic order of authors. Which bibliography style are you using?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for replying. I'm using {plain}

Comment: so I'd expect them in alphabetic order rather than order in the bib file?  (that is the order I find most natural but use style `unsrt` if you do not want them sorted in to order and appear in order of first reference)

Comment: Many thanks indeed. Using unsrt has done the trick.  I was just about to give up in disgust. Unfortunately, being relatively new to this site, I am not sure how to give you a recommendation.

Comment: you can accept the answer once I post an answer (I just made a comment as I wasn't sure that was the issue as your problem description was a bit misleading saying the bib file order was being used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the entries in the bib file has no effect but most bibtex styles either sort the entries into alphabetic order of author names (like `plain`) or do not sort at all, in which case the entries come out in order of first reference (like `unsrt`).